# How to compare two string array and find the index number of the common string array and apply it to the third string array?

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have three string arrays

```
string[] stringArray= {"AAA", "BBB", "CCC","DDD", "EEE","FFF","GGG","HHH" };
string[] stringArray1 = { "A", "B", "C","D", "E","F","G","H" };
string[] stringArray2 = { "BBB", "DDD","FFF","HHH" };
```

How could I compare `stringArray2` with `stringArray` and find the index number `stringArray` that matches.
After finding the index ,I need to apply it to `stringArray1`
and display the results.

I have tried the following code ,but failed to get the match string

```
int j=0;
string line = null;
List<string> finalstring = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.Count; i++)
{ 
   while(stringArray[i] == stringArray2[j])
   {
      line = stringArray2[i];
      finalstring.Add(line);
      j++;
   }
}
```

Comment: What will be the final result that you are expecting?

Comment: finalstring as ={"B","D","F","H"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to try like this:

```
var result = stringArray1.Where(c => // iterating stringArray1
             stringArray2.Where(x => stringArray.Contains(x)) // filtering stringArray2 elements
                         .Any(y=>y.Contains(c))).ToList(); // collect the final result
```

A [Working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NHoH2v) for your reference

Answer (score 1):

```
int j=0;
string line = null;
List<string> finalstring = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.Length; i++)
//for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.Count; i++)   // <-- Count is not proper way to get total elements in an array
{
   j = 0;  // <-- you failed to reinitialize 'j' 
   //while(stringArray[i] == stringArray2[j])  // <-- while is not proper way to compare
   if(stringArray[i] == stringArray2[j])
   {
      //line = stringArray2[i];

      //if only first charracter is needed
      finalstring.Add(new string(stringArray2[i][0], 1));

      //if complete string is needed
      //finalstring.Add(stringArray2[i]);

      j++;
   }
}
```

Above is not an optimized way to do the comparisons. You can try using [HashSet class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
    string[] stringArray= {"AAA", "BBB", "CCC","DDD", "EEE","FFF","GGG","HHH" };
    string[] stringArray1 = { "A", "B", "C","D", "E","F","G","H" };
    string[] stringArray2 = { "BBB", "DDD","FFF","HHH" };

    //convert string array to hashset
    var hashSet = new HashSet<string>(stringArray);

    int j=0;
    string line = null;
    List<string> finalstring = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < stringArray2.Length; i++)
    {
        if(hashSet.Contains(stringArray2[i]))
        {
            //if only first charracter is needed
            finalstring.Add(new string(stringArray2[i][0], 1));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<string> finalList = new List<string>();
stringArray.Select((value,index) => new { value, index })
.Where(num => stringArray2.Contains(num.value)).ToList()
.ForEach(num => finalList.Add(stringArray1[num.index]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare the elements on same index but you have to search the element of `stringArray2` in `stringArray`. You can use [Array.IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eddebat(v=vs.110).aspx) to find in Array the required element.

```
string[] stringArray= {"AAA", "BBB", "CCC","DDD", "EEE","FFF","GGG","HHH" };
string[] stringArray1 = { "A", "B", "C","D", "E","F","G","H" };
string[] stringArray2 = { "BBB", "DDD","FFF","HHH" };
    int j=0;
string line = null;
List<string> finalstring = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < stringArray2.Count(); i++)
{ 
   if(Array.IndexOf(stringArray, stringArray2[i]) != -1)
   {
      int idx = Array.IndexOf(stringArray1, stringArray2[i][0].ToString());
      if(idx!=-1)
        finalstring.Add(stringArray1[idx]);
    }  
}
```

**Edit** using [Linq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693042.aspx)

```
var result2 = stringArray1.Where(c=>
              stringArray2.Intersect(stringArray)
              .Any(i=>i.Contains(c)));
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do it with selecting the index via Linq (`where >= 0` filters out all non matches):

```
string[] stringArray = { "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE", "FFF", "GGG", "HHH" };
string[] stringArray1 = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H" };
string[] stringArray2 = { "BBB", "DDD", "FFF", "HHH" };

var matches = stringArray2
    .Select(s => Array.FindIndex(stringArray, s2 => s2 == s))
    .Where(i => i >= 0).Select(i => stringArray1[i])
    .ToList();
```

Here a [`dotnetfiddle`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/X65STE)